# Does my code sufficiently prevent overflow?

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, fopen, buffer-overflow

In my C program, in the case of file i/o, is it sufficient to put this:

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(*fp));
```

In the case that I use:

```
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(*fp), fp) != NULL) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Will I ever get a buffer overflow by writing to buffer, in this case?

Comment: Are you assuming `sizeof(*fp)` will give you the size of the file?

Comment: Assuming the size of the content you want to read from the file into `buffer` exceeds the size of a `FILE` structure,you'll get an overflow.`sizeof(*fp)` is the size of a `FILE` structure object.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll never get a buffer overflow.  But it looks like you think `sizeof(*fp)` is yielding the size of the file, which it isn't.  That's giving you the size of a `FILE` structure.